# How can I translate the password reset email in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to translate the password reset email, which is English by default, in Laravel 5.7.

Normally – for the login, registration, and password reset views – you would translate the files under `/resources/lang/`, but I can't find the corresponding lines for the body on the emails.

How can I translate the password reset email?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the method `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword::toMail()` you can see the `Lang::getFromJson()` method is used to populate the email:

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password Notification'))
    ->line(Lang::getFromJson('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
    ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password'), url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
    ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
```

So you should be able to add these translations to the `resources/lang/xx.json` file [as described in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#defining-translation-strings) (scroll down to "Using Translation Strings As Keys.")

This also applies to the email verification message in `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail`.

For example, this could be the content of `resources/lang/fr.json` (forgive my high school French from 25 years ago)

```
{
    "If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.": "Si vous ne demandez pas le réinitialisation de votre mot de passe, vous ne pouvez rien faire"
}
```

---

For both classes, the template file `Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php` contains additional text that is in standard Blade `@lang` tags, which can be translated using message files at `resources/lang/xx/messages.php`

For example, this could be the content of `resources/lang/fr/messages.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    "Regards" => "Félicitations",
];
```

Answer (score 11):

Just found out that you can also translate the `@lang` tags within your json file:

```
{
  "Regards": "Met vriendelijke groet",
  "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)": "Als u problemen ondervindt bij het klikken op de knop \":actionText\" kopieert en plakt u de onderstaande URL in uw webbrowser\n[:actionURL](:actionURL)",
  "All rights reserved.": "Alle rechten voorbehouden."
}
```

---

Look at the repository for all translation files:

https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Tested under Laravel 8. Just copy your .json file in /resources/lang and be sure to match your locale in /config/app.php